# Multiple touches on a single button android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I have an app with buttons and I am trying to handle multitouch events. Currently I am using the on touch method and looking for `MotionEven.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEven.ACTION_UP` to keep track of touch events. This works fine if two buttons are touched at the same time. However, I want to have the buttons have one behavior when touched with a single finger and different behavior when touched with more fingers. For example, if you touch a button with one finger that button turns red, if you touch a button with 2 fingers that button turns yellow, if you touch a button with 3 fingers it turns green, and so on.

The problem I am running into is that when I touch a button with more than one finger, the second touch does not seem to trigger an event. How can I detect multiple touches on the same button?

Comment: https://github.com/devunwired/custom-touch-examples this repository might help.

Comment: Which exact example am I looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basics of what you want.  It may not be completely what you want because there must be some space between fingers for the `MotionEvent`s I used to be recognized.  If 2 fingers are close together, it gives `ACTION_MOVE` as the `MotionEvent`.  If you really need, you may be able to interpret those & determine if 2 or more fingers are down close together. [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MAX_TOUCHES = 3;

    private View buttonView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        buttonView = findViewById(R.id.button_view);
        buttonView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            boolean eventConsumed = false;

            // Only handling these 4 events means that there must be some space
            //      between fingers when touching
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "" + motionEvent.toString());
                switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        setButtonColor(motionEvent.getPointerCount());
                        eventConsumed = true;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        // subtract 1 from the count, this event still includes the touch just removed
                        setButtonColor(motionEvent.getPointerCount() - 1);
                        eventConsumed = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return eventConsumed;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setButtonColor(int count) {
        Log.d(TAG, "count = " + count);

        if(count < 0) {
            count = 0;
        } else if(count > MAX_TOUCHES) {
            count = MAX_TOUCHES;
        }

        switch (count) {
            case 0:
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getButtonColor(R.color.colorNotPressed));
                break;

            case 1:
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getButtonColor(R.color.colorRed));
                break;

            case 2:
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getButtonColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                break;

            case 3:
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getButtonColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // This keeps you from getting a warning about getResources().getColor() being deprecated
    @SuppressWarnings(value = "deprecation")
    private int getButtonColor(int id) {
        int color;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            color = getColor(id);
        } else {
            color = getResources().getColor(id);
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (not including AppBar or FAB stuff)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Big Button"
        android:background="@color/colorNotPressed"
        android:id="@+id/button_view"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Big Button"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With these in your colors.xml file

```
<color name="colorNotPressed">#606060</color>
<color name="colorRed">#FF0000</color>
<color name="colorYellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="colorGreen">#00FF00</color>
```